# Como agregar opciones a un select en caso de que no exista?

Tags: html, html5

Buenas estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel 7 y en mi vista tengo un formulario para agregar presupuestos, y uno de los campos es un select con opciones de validez:

```
                   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="validez">Validez</label>
                        <select name="validez" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Seleccionar </option>
                          <option value="2">2 Dias</option>
                          <option value="4">4 Dias</option>
                          <option value="7">7 Dias</option>
                          <option value="15">15 Dias</option>
                          <option value="30">30 Dias</option>
                          
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer pero no se como, es que en este select es que el usuario pueda agregar una opción al select en caso que esa opción no se encuentre. Alguno sabe como puedo realizar esto?

Comment: Pues lo que se me ocurre es que le des una opcion ya sea en el mismo select o en un boton a parte para agregar mas opciones al select, es decir que al presionar el boton 'agregar nueva opcion' te despliegue un modal y solo lo rellenes y lo guardes, ya despues de guardarlo solo refrescas esa parte.

Comment: Adicional a eso necesitas tener una Base de datos para guardar las opciones, si lo quisieras solo en tu html de manera local solo para el usuario que use esa maquina, puedes guadarlo en el Local Storage en archivo .JSON

Comment: @JonathanG Tengo una base de datos